# Find the Linear transformation from the Matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image: q]

In this question, I assume the first basis is for the polynomial being transformed and the second for the output polynomial.

Even then while I have a set of equations I can't figure out how to write the transform itself. Below you can find my attempt. I kind of brute forced a solution. I especially do not like having to use "ix" as the argument. Seeing as the question is worth 18 marks it must be tricky. If you can tell me a structured way to tackle these kinds of problems, I would be grateful.

[image: sol]

---

UPDATE :

I tried what @EuYu suggested and I am ending up with another matrix but now it describes the transformation from standard basis to standard basis. But still, I'll need to find some $T(f_1(x)) = f_2(x)$ while what I have here is a transformation of the coefficients of the polynomial.

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

Comment: It's a tedious problem, but conceptually it's no different from an ordinary change-of-basis. Do you know how to perform a change of basis for the matrix representation if the basis for the domain and codomain were equal?

Comment: @EuYu Yes. Like given the old basis and new basis. I understand how to find the new coordinate vector from the old coordinate vector. But in this case I need to find the transformation itself right? I am not able to see how to use a change of basis to get the transformation

Comment: "Finding" the linear transform is a little misleading. The transform is already given to you. Given the matrix representation $A$, there is a unique linear transform $T$ that it represents, so it really doesn't make sense to "find" the linear transform. What the question is really asking is to display the transform in a more standard form. This means essentially changing from the given basis (which are not so nice) into a more standard one, for example $\{1,x,x^2\}$. This is just one big change of basis problem, where the complication is that the basis of the domain and codomain are unequal.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Let me try working in this direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EuYu I made both of the basis equal to the standard basis. But the matrix I get is a transform on the coefficients rather than the polynomial as a whole.